# TypeError: Method "getRange" of null when using multiple scripts (Libraries) in Google scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, global-variables, libraries

I have a serious problem when using Libraries in Google Sheets.

I have two Spreadsheets: Dashboard1 and Dashboard2. In both spreadsheets, I have multiple scripts and Triggers.

There is one trigger in specific that triggers on event OnEdit in Dashboard2. Here is the code:

**Dashboard2**

*Code.gs*

```
function onEdit(e){
  Dashboard1.updateReferral(e.oldValue, e.value);
}
```

**Dashboard1**

*Code.gs*

```
function updateReferral(evaluatedEmail, newReferral){
  var employee = returnEmployeeRow(evaluatedEmail);
  PAYROLL_SHEET.getRange(REFERRAL_COLUMN + employee[2]).setValue(newReferral);
}
```

*Constants.gs*

```
var SHEET_CATEGORIES = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Categorias");
var RANGE_CATEGORIES = SHEET_CATEGORIES.getRange("A2:G");
var CATEGORIES = RANGE_CATEGORIES.getValues();
```

What I want to do is when someone edit in Dashboard2, it updates a single row in Dashboard1.

When I tried to trigger the event, it throws the error

`TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 2, file "Constants", project "XXXXXX")`

I figured out that this error exist because there is no sheet "Categorias" in Dashboard2.
If I create a sheet "Categorias" in Dashboard2, it works fine.

My question is:

1. This is a normal behavior? Why when I run the code, it tries to initialize the variable from Constants.gs in Dashboard1 as they exist in Dashboard2?
2. There is a solution for this? Or just I can't do this?

I've tried to use different name in the .gs files but it didn't work.
Also tried to delete the file Constants.gs and have all the variables in Code.gs.

Answer (score 2):

From the OP's question

> My question is:
>
> 1. This is a normal behavior? Why when I run the code, it tries to initialize the variable from Constants.gs in Dashboard1 as they exist in Dashboard2?

Yes, this behavior is "normal".

> 2. There is a solution for this? Or just I can't do this?

There are many solutions. Some rules of "thumb" for Google Apps Script projects that could help you decide how to procede:

1. Reduce the variable declarations at the global scope and when you declare variables at the global scope limit them to assign literals.
2. Only use stand-alone projects for libraries but if you really need to use a bounded project as a library, don't use "getActive" methods on the library functions, instead add the "active" object as an argument on the library functions that require them.

Related

- [GAS: Problems in using global variables in functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12106723/1595451)
- [Variable scope between spreadsheet script and script library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13338086/1595451)
- [Calling variables at global scope and comparing it in Google apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17323457/1595451)
- [Using Global vars in GAS, is it advisable? are there any downsides?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30013661/1595451)

Comment: Thanks Rubén!! Now I' get it. I need to read a lot of how Google Scripts works.